# IIS wfastcgi django request timeout after 100s, how to make it longer?

Tags: python, django, iis, wfastcgi

i got a django app to extract some data from very big tables.
the users are ok with the long waiting time.
but every time the users visit the url, it timeout after 100s.
How to make it waiting longer? IIs seems to have no configuration for this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you could try below steps to modify the IIS web application's advanced setting.

1.Open the IIS management console and right click the site.

2.Open property "Manage Web Site" and click "Advance Settings".

3.Expand Limits and modify the timeout value.

[image]